# binary tree creation in SCALA

Tags: scala, tree, binary

```
scala> def buildTree[A](list:List[A]):BinTree[A]=list match{
     | case Nil=>Leaf
     | case x :: xs =>{
     | val k = xs.length/2
     | Branch(x,buildTree(xs.take(k)),buildTree(xs.drop(k))
     | )
     | }
     | }
```

but  its saying :- error: not found: type BinTree
                :-error: not found: value Branch
                :-error: not found: value Leaf

Comment: Could you share a piece of code of binary tree?

Comment: scala> def buildTree[A](list:List[A]):BinTree[A]=list match{
     | case Nil=>Leaf
     | case x :: xs =>{
     | val k = xs.length/2
     | Branch(x,buildTree(xs.take(k)),buildTree(xs.drop(k))
     | )
     | }
     | }
it is also in the question

Comment: Where are `BinTree`, `Leaf` and `Branch` defined?

Comment: ohh, I thought thees are keywords,
could you help me with what i should be theese?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
trait BinTree[+A]
case object Leaf extends BinTree[Nothing]
case class Branch[+A](node: A, left: BinTree[A], right: BinTree[A]) extends BinTree[A]

def buildTree[A](list: List[A]): BinTree[A] = list match {
 case Nil => Leaf
 case x :: xs =>
    val (left, right) = xs.splitAt(xs.length/2)

    Branch(x, buildTree(left), buildTree(right))
}
```

But you really need to get familiar with some of the basics of Scala before trying more complex stuff like this.

Comment: Thanks ! got it, i am working on my basic and learning things , I am new bee to this.